# Server Errors while accessing Azure MobileServices TableController

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I created a **TableController** API using the **Azure Mobile App** Template and deployed to azure.

I tested from URL and it's working fine when I use the below URL

```
http://rkXXXXXXXXXXX.azurewebsites.net/tables/Person/f90cb37d51a34f8cb97432a57000c876?ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0
```

Now I created the **Xamarin Forms** app to consume it and I am receiving **Internal Server Error** in the logs and not able to use it.

```
public IMobileServiceTable<Person> PersonOnlineTable { get; set; }
PersonOnlineTable = client.GetTable<Person>();
    public async Task SavePersonAsync(Person item)
    {
        if (item.Id == null)
        {
            await PersonOnlineTable.InsertAsync(item);
        }
        else
        {
            await PersonOnlineTable.UpdateAsync(item);
        }
    }
```

***Azure Logging Error***

```
Detailed Error Information:
Module     __DynamicModule_Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35_78a91520-ed4c-4317-9401-f8ad17a561a6
Notification       PreExecuteRequestHandler
Handler    ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0
Error Code     0x00000000

Requested URL      http://rkXXXXXXXXXXX:80/tables/Person/f90cb37d51a34f8cb97432a57000c876
Physical Path      D:\home\site\wwwroot\tables\Person\f90cb37d51a34f8cb97432a57000c876
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous
```

***Exception Received In Application:***

```
{Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException: The request could not be completed.  (Internal Server Error)
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient+<ThrowInvalidResponse>d__24.MoveNext () [0x001ec] in <42e24ce875d34485ad11c4f8aebb904a>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient+<SendRequestAsync>d__26.MoveNext () [0x000fc] in <42e24ce875d34485ad11c4f8aebb904a>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient+<RequestAsync>d__18.MoveNext () [0x000fa] in <42e24ce875d34485ad11c4f8aebb904a>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable+<>c__DisplayClass26_0+<<UpdateAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext () [0x000d4] in <42e24ce875d34485ad11c4f8aebb904a>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable+<TransformHttpException>d__43.MoveNext () [0x000bb] in <42e24ce875d34485ad11c4f8aebb904a>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable+<UpdateAsync>d__26.MoveNext () [0x00121] in <42e24ce875d34485ad11c4f8aebb904a>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable`1+<TransformHttpException>d__31[T].MoveNext () [0x000a0] in <42e24ce875d34485ad11c4f8aebb904a>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable`1+<UpdateAsync>d__8[T].MoveNext () [0x000e2] in <42e24ce875d34485ad11c4f8aebb904a>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable`1+<UpdateAsync>d__7[T].MoveNext () [0x00067] in <42e24ce875d34485ad11c4f8aebb904a>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at UXD.Services.PersonService+<SavePersonAsync>d__9.MoveNext () [0x000a4] in c:\RK\Services\PersonService.cs:268 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
  at UXD.ViewModel.PersonViewModel+<ExecuteAddPersonCommandAsync>d__19.MoveNext () [0x00040] in c:\RK\ViewModel\PersonViewModel.cs:106 }
```

I tried deploying the server application multiple times and its always working from the MainURL and not working when calling from App. Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: What happens if you debug the mobile sevice locally and point your app to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue happened because of the Datatype mismatch in the model object. I have datetime objects where defined as **datetimeoffset** in the database and **datetime** in the DTO object. After changing my DTO object's datatype it worked fine.